# Unable to write large files to raid after adding a new disk

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I have a RAID 0 setup with 2 2TB drive that has been running fine for years. I typically copy large files from a couple of windows machines to it.

It is now low on space (100GB left) so I purchased 2 6TB drives to expand it. I started following the instructions [here](http://www.tjansson.dk/2015/12/growing-a-mdadm-raid-by-replacing-disks/). I got as far as removing the first old disk and adding the first new one. I then waited 5 hours until the raid finished resync.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

Now shows

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Jul 16 19:53:16 2014
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Tue Aug 27 09:54:26 2019
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : mediafile:0  (local to host mediafile)
              UUID : 11763b77:0cb23304:c505f457:46e2a644
            Events : 671

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
```

Reading the existing files is no problem. However when trying to copy over new large files to the array I get an error 0x8007003B in windows. Small files of a couple of MB still work.

Both old and new drives are ext4. The only difference I can see is the disklable is `dos` for the old disk and `gpt` for the new. Could this be the issue and if so will replacing the second old disk fix it? I hesitant to go forward until I understand better whats happening.

Comment: cant you plug all 4 disks?

Comment: @cmak.fr The server only has 2 sata ports. O might be able to get a usb shell for them but what how would this help me?

Comment: @mook765 it's a network issue from what I've read, not necessary windows. As windows was writing to the RAID without problems for years I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: @Dowlers From your output, the raid array looks clean. And for sure, it has nothing to do with with the partition table style (GPT/dos). The symptom you describe is what is reported by many Windows users, it's not only you. Probably some restriction introduced by Microsoft recently, who knows. A lot of links I checked recommend to disable antivirus temporary, some also disable Windows firewall for the transfer of bigger files, so this is at least something you could try.

Comment: I did some further testing and the problem is the network , not the raid. I plugged a USB drive into the server and was able to copy a large file directly to the raid. I tried to copy the same file from another Linux machine across the network and it also failed. So somehow I damaged the network card or the Ethernet port when I was opening up the server. Thanks for your help @mook765 and cmak.ka